# Structures vs classes in swift

Tags: swift

I was reading about type erasure in swift. After reading an article, I decided to write a simple implementation of "chain of responsibility" pattern and came up with this solution:

```
protocol Responsibility {
    associatedtype ParameterType
    associatedtype ResultType

    func process(_ data: ParameterType) -> ResultType?
}

struct AnyResponsibility<ParameterType, ResultType>: Responsibility {
    private let processData: (ParameterType) -> ResultType?

    init<R: Responsibility>(_ responsibility: R) where R.ParameterType == ParameterType, R.ResultType == ResultType {
        processData = responsibility.process
    }

    func process(_ data: ParameterType) -> ResultType? {
        processData(data)
    }
}

protocol ResponsibilityChain {
    associatedtype ParameterType
    associatedtype ResultType

    var responsibilities: [AnyResponsibility<ParameterType, ResultType>] { get }
}

struct AnyResponsibilityChain<ParameterType, ResultType>: ResponsibilityChain {
    init<Chain: ResponsibilityChain>(_ chain: Chain) where Chain.ParameterType == ParameterType, Chain.ResultType == ResultType {
        responsibilities = chain.responsibilities
    }

    let responsibilities: [AnyResponsibility<ParameterType, ResultType>]
}

struct MyResponsibility: Responsibility {
    func process(_ data: Int) -> Int? {
        data + 1
    }
}

struct MyChain: ResponsibilityChain {
    init(_ responsibilities: [AnyResponsibility<Int, Int>]) {
        self.responsibilities = responsibilities
    }

    let responsibilities: [AnyResponsibility<Int, Int>]
}
```

However, in example code from this article: https://www.donnywals.com/understanding-type-erasure-in-swift/ they seem to favor classes over structures. Is there any good reason why it would be better to use classes in my code?

I know that classes are reference types but I always favor `let` over `var` so it shouldn't matter in this case. Am I right? I have also read this article: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html but I didn't found any solution to my problem.

I'm coming to swift from C++ background and we tend to use classes when the object has some logic, and use structures when the object only holds some properties. Is it a case in swift?

Comment: There isn't any good reason for preferring a class in the code you've given. Compare https://robnapier.net/erasure.

Comment: As far as I know, "type ensures" are not a thing. I think you meant type *erasures*.

Comment: I wouldn't use structs or classes here. What you've built are just closures, and I would treat them as closures. `let responsibilities: [(Int) -> Int?]`. All the rest is just adding unhelpful complexity. If you have something more complicated, then show that. There is no single design that works for all problems. The right solution depends on the details of the problem. In my experience, if you think you want a type eraser, first reconsider your design. They are a useful tool, but they're not a first tool to reach for. I wish I'd said that more clearly in the blog post, but I learned it later.

Comment: @RobNapier Yes that's true but I created that code as an exercise to practice type erasure. I fully agree that this code is too complex but it will do as an exercise.

Comment: If you want an exercise in type erasure, I highly recommend rebuilding AnySequence from stdlib. It is a very good example and shows the complexity of building a good one. That said, I have never once had to use it AnySequence in real code, which is the norm for type erasers. They have turned out to be a much less useful tool than they appear.